# Lotus Notes: How to add a button to the existing mail template?

Tags: lotus-notes

I need to add a new button "Send to SysAdmin" to our existing mail template. It should be located along with the New Message, Reply, etc. buttons.

I'm editing the mail template with Designer and it is quite confusing. Is it a View, Folder, Action?

Where do I start?

In the past I've been able to setup an agent to automatically forward mail to a specific address, but this time is different since I need an actual button to show.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that if you want that button to appear only when the user is in their Inbox folder, then what you need to do is create an Action within the design of the Inbox, and you would do this by going into the Folders list in Domino Designer and opening the $Inbox folder, then bring up the Action pane, and *add* the Action.  But if you want this button to appear no matter whether the user is in their Inbox folder, their Sent view, or anywhere else, then what you're going to want to do is create a Shared Action (go into the Code section of the template in Domino Designer and select Shared Actions), and then you are going to open the various views and folders where you want it to appear, bring up the Action pane and *insert* the Shared Action.

*Note:  This question might be better on StackOverflow instead of on SuperUser, because it's really a Notes programming question and there are a lot more people answering Notes programming questions there.  I'll leave it to you as to whether you want to move it over there.*